# Records deleted from database after running Java code

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have connected a MySQL database to my Java Spring MVC code, with hibernate and entities.

I have added records to my Clients table in MySQL, and successfully fetched the records from Intelij.

However, after running the following code, all the records were deleted from my database.

```
package com.example.WebAppProcess20.Entities;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class dbCheck {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        ArrayList<ClientsEntity> li = (ArrayList<ClientsEntity>)session.createQuery("from ClientsEntity").list();
        for (ClientsEntity c: li) {
            System.out.println(c.getClientName());
        }
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Can you please explain why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `ddl` setting in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` is set to recreate the schema each time you run your application, by which all the data will be wiped at each run. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710074/hibernate-always-deletes-all-data-from-a-table-on-its-own/3710918#3710918) link (thanks @notyou) on how to modify it in order to keep previous data.